How should I run cable across a steel beam?
I’ve seen a lot of questions on the internet about running wire along the length of steel beams in basements. I have a little different of a situation.
I have installed a steel beam in my kitchen to replace a load-bearing wall. I have modified this steel beam so that I can hang the floor joists on it. This means I’m unable to use steel beam clips that I have seen online to adhere wire or conduit to it (see image)
I’m beginning to run 14-3 wire into the ceiling for my lighting, but would love to cross my beam in order to avoid going around or into the basement with the wire (feels excessive and messy). Ideally the wire and whatever I use to secure it remain above the bottom of the floor joists, since the whole reason I put a steel beam in was to have a flush ceiling between the rooms. The joists hang about 1/2" below the bottom of the beam.
Any ideas for how I could protect and attach the wire to this beam?
NOTE: Any concerns or questions about the joist hangers can be discussed here. Worth noting I have since drilled new holes in the few hangers that had questionable nail placements and drove new nails in.


What is the depth that the joists hang below the beam?

it's only about 1/2"

I already see cable running through some joists here. Why is it necessary to run under the beam specifically?

@AdamO Those cables have been cut. They're old, from before the beam. No cables currently run under or over the new beam.

@KoreyKostek I am asking a separate question. If you ran new cable, why not pull the deprecated cable and run new cable through the existing joist holes? If you needed a perpendicular run under the beam, I don't believe you need to fasten the cable to the beam, but I think a nailing plate would be useful - flush to the finished dry wall and fastened to the joists.

@AdamO I do need to run perpendicular to the beam, that's my conundrum, since I will be running all lighting across both "rooms" that beam separates. That makes sense about fastening it on either side, I was just thinking about how to protect the wire from drilling as it runs flush to the bottom of the beam. I really don't anticipate drilling through the ceiling while I'm at the house, but wanted to use best practices.

Regarding my earlier comment about your joist hangers (now removed), see this question. I'll give Michael Karas a chance to migrate his answer before responding myself.

Just one quick thought: Your Local Authority Having Jurisdiction (ie, your town inspector) will need to review whatever you do. Might be a good idea to ask them first, so you aren't at risk of having to rip it out and redo it

Am I wrong in seeing a gap at the top of the wooden beam that you have bolted on to the steel beam?

@MikeB there is a gap, which I am frustrated about. I am doing my best to fill that gap snuggly along the entire length of the beam.

@KoreyKostek  Can you not use that gap for your cable?

@MikeB I'd rather not run the risk of the cables being squished over time.

Since running through existing joist holes, or even boring new ones, seems the best way to run cable parallel to the beam, it seems OP's question could be reduced to how to achieve perpendicular runs over the beam. I have this image to suggest how this could be done.


that's incredible! Thank you. Is there any problem some clever blocking can't solve?

The hardest part about this solution is being very meticulous with measurements as far as drywall finishing. I guess you're already planning some strapping. You may need to plane down straps under the nail plate. But good luck!

also it doesn't need to be circular holes. you could cut notches instead, also if you don't fully drive the nails that go into the beam it will allow easier adustment of the height of the plate.

For a 14awg wiring you may consider running the connections that cross the beam using metal jacketed cabling that extends fully between junction boxes on each end. This type cable is often referred to as "BX electrical cable".
BX cable for lighting is typically small enough in diameter that it could be routed under your steel beam but you may need to consider additional shield protection to remain code compliant  due to the cable running just over the lower ceiling covering you may use on the bottom of the joists.
I see from your photo that you have already drilled holes through your steel beam and the ledger joist that you bolted to the side of the beam.

Picture snipped from question.
Maybe you can drill similar hole through the beam to allow passing the BX type metal sheathed type cable through the beam instead of trying to sneak it under the beam.

To be safe, consult a structural engineer before drilling holes in structural steel beams. It's probably fine, but there's likely sizing and offset restrictions you'll need to be careful of, lest you compromise the integrity. (And those might vary based on the exact situation.) If you can use the same firm which speced the original install (especially if it's recent), it might be a minimal cost add-on. If you're really lucky, they'll simply point to the location on the existing engineering diagrams where they've already accounted for the possibility.
